# Setting the value for a paragraph with innerHTML, isn't working

Tags: javascript

The `innerHTML` isn't working in this JavaScript code.

```
var date = new Date();
var time = date.getHours();
var morning = document.p.getElementById("greeting").innerHTML="Good Morning ";
var afternoon = document.write =  "Good Afternoon ";
var evening = document.write = "Good evening";

if (time < 12){
    morning}
else if (time < 18){
afternoon}
else {evening};
```

The HTML code is

```
<p id="greeting"> </p>
```

I am trying to get the code to read "good morning" or "afternoon", based on the time. The JavaScript is in an external file. It worked with `document.write` but in the external file, the greeting appears at the top of the page.

Here I am trying to set a

of ‘greeting’ based on time of day.

Comment: Why do you use `innerHTML` one place and `document.write` another?

Comment: why `evening = document.write = "Good evening";` are you assigning to the `document.write` method? Keep in mind that `document.write` clears the whole document!

Comment: I have since gained significant JavaScript knowledge. Using two = in one statements not next to each other doesn’t make sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var afternoon = document.write = "Good afternoon";
```

What this does is to introduce a variable called `afternoon` and to set both it *and* the property `write` on `document`, which was previously a function call, to the string `"Good afternoon"`.

At a later point in your code, you just write `afternoon`, which accesses the variable, but doesn't do anything with it.

It looks like you want to do something like this:

```
var morning = function() { document.getElementById("greeting").innerHTML="Good Morning "; };
var afternoon = function() { document.getElementById("greeting").innerHTML="Good Afternoon "; };
var evening = function() { document.getElementById("greeting").innerHTML="Good evening"; };

if (time < 12) {
   morning();
} else if (time < 18) {
   afternoon();
} else {
   evening();
};
```

That is, the above would be the closest thing to your code, that is somewhat correct. I would still say that there is room for some improvement. Something like the following would make more sense to me:

```
var morning = 'Good Morning ';
var afternoon = 'Good Afternoon ';
var evening = 'Good evening';

if(time < 12) {
    document.getElementById("greeting").innerHTML = morning;
} else if (time < 18) {
    document.getElementById("greeting").innerHTML = afternoon;
} else {
    document.getElementById("greeting").innerHTML = evening;
}
```

Better yet, you could probably decide which message you want to use first, and then assign it, which would give you fewer places to change your code if you want to change where to output the greeting, for instance:

```
var messages = {
   morning: 'Good Morning ',
   afternoon: 'Good Afternoon ',
   evening: 'Good evening'
};

var greeting = time < 12 
    ? messages.morning 
    : time < 18 
        ? messages.afternoon 
        : messages.evening;

document.getElementById('greeting').innerHTML = greeting;
```

Comment: I have been trying allsorts of this this morning. I tried your solutions but didnt work.

Comment: @AdrianMcGuinness: [works here](http://jsfiddle.net/p6xfB/). What problem are you experiencing?

Comment: it isnt appearing in my browser

Comment: @AdrianMcGuinness: what browser might that be? should work in webkit browsers and IE

Comment: im using chrome, I saw u used jsfiddle. Im using that, its useful

Comment: @AdrianMcGuinness: I'm not sure I follow. Is your problem solved?

Answer (score 3):

```
document.p.getElementById("greeting")
```

should be

```
document.getElementById("greeting")
```

Comment: This should probably be a comment, because it doesn't come a very long way to explain the misconceptions that have lead up to this question.

Answer (score 2):

try Replacing this

```
var morning = document.p.getElementById("greeting").innerHTML="Good Morning ";
```

with

```
var morning = document.getElementById("greeting").innerHTML="Good Morning ";
```

Comment: Thanks I saw my error in document.p.getElementById and document.write thanks

Answer (score 2):

Remove `p.` from `document.p.getElementById`

**Correct one:**

```
document.getElementById("greeting").innerHTML="Good Morning ";
```

Comment: Agree, I’m looking for the element with ‘getelementbyid’ adding a p before doesn’t make it easier. It’s to do with the element.